How to log withAuthenticator to understand why this error is occurring when I try to sign in?
I am trying to sign in with a user that I have just created. Cognito even shows this user in the user pool: |
And the identity pool id matches up between the identity pool section of Cognito and aws-exports.js under 'aws_cognito_identity_pool_id'.
The code I have used is all from this tutorial and I have followed every step https://blog.logrocket.com/aws-amplify-react-native-tutorial-examples/
Can anyone help me work out why I am not able to progress to the signed in state? Providing some logs here would be helpful, but I am not used to withAuthenticator so I'm not sure whats the best way to do this.
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsExports from './src/aws-exports';
import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react-native';
Amplify.configure(awsExports);
function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default withAuthenticator(App)


